# Compile error during compilation with javac | Groovy

Tags: groovy, compilation, gradle

Have an err with compiling *gradle idea*
error see on screen
http://upwap.ru/1884422

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'code-quality'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'project-reports'

sourceCompatibility = 1.6 archivesBaseName = 'opas-client'

ideaModule { downloadJavadoc = true }

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenRepo urls: "f:/dev/lib/"
    }
}

version = '0.1'

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {taskGraph ->
    if (taskGraph.hasTask(':release')) {
        version = '0.1.2' //    } else { //        version = '1.0.624'
    }
}

repositories {
      mavenRepo urls: "f:/dev/lib/" 
}


dependencies {   
  groovy group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '1.7.5'

  compile  'log4j:log4j:1.2.14',
       'com.caucho:hessian:4.0.7',
       'com.toedter:jcalendar:1.3.2',
       'org.springframework:spring-context-support:3.0.5.RELEASE',
       'org.springframework:spring-web:3.0.5.RELEASE',
       'com.jgoodies:looks:2.2.2',
       'com.jgoodies:animation:1.2.0',
       'com.jgoodies:binding:2.0.6',
       'com.jgoodies:forms:1.2.1',
       'com.jgoodies:validation:2.0.1'

  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.7',
             'org.unitils:unitils-spring:3.1',
             'org.unitils:unitils-easymock:3.1',
             'org.unitils:unitils-inject:3.1',
             'org.springframework:spring-test:3.0.5.RELEASE' 
}

manifest.mainAttributes(
    'Implementation-Title': 'victoria',
    'Implementation-Version': version,
    'Main-Class': 'com.sirius.opas.client.Client',
    'Class-Path':manifestClasspath() )

task release(dependsOn: 'jar') << {
    ant.delete(dir:releaseDir, quiet:"true" )
    ant.mkdir(dir:releaseDir)

    copy {
       from configurations.compile
       into "${releaseDir}/${releaseLibDir}"            
     }

    copy {
       from "$libsDir/${archivesBaseName}-${version}.jar"
       from "dist/start.sh"
       from "dist/start.cmd"
       into "${releaseDir}"
    } 
}

String manifestClasspath() {
    String classes = ""
    configurations.compile.files.each { file ->
        classes += " ${releaseLibDir}/${file.name}"
    }
    return classes   
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: in zip http://club-android.ru/build.zip

Comment: Why not just post the error and script in the question rather than link to resources which will be gone at some point. This question as it stands will be of no use to future users of StackOverflow

Comment: @OlegBeat Please post the error message itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are simply missing a dependency that provides `BeanDefinition` class. Try adding `'org.springframework:spring-beans:3.0.5.RELEASE'` to your `compile` dependencies list.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be in your `build.gradle` file.